# Effect of VISA refusal reason quoted on Denmark green card visa application?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

One or more Member State(s) consider you to be a threat to public policy, internal security or public health as defined in Article 2(19) of Regulations Ec No 562/2006 (Shengen Borders Code) or to the international relations of one or more of the Member States.

will my denmark green card application is prone to decline due to the past schegen visa refusal reasons?

With the above refusal reason, I am not sure whether my name is listed in SIS.

Is there a way to clear the name out of the record.. whom should i contact and what it takes in terms of time and money?

Please advice.